# Put a font slightly over another with z-index in chrome[html]?

Tags: html, css

```css
.a {
  font-family: "Itim", cursive;
  z-index: 1;
}

.b {
  font-family: "Sedgwick Ave", cursive;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Itim|Sedgwick+Ave" rel="stylesheet">
<p class="a">Back Font</p>
<p class="b">Front Font</p>
```

I get the fonts that I want, but `margin-bottom: 50px` isn't doing the effect that I wanted, that effect is to put the class b over class slightly over class a, so that it looks (kind of) like 3D text.

Comment: If one is supposed to be the shadow of the other, why are they different fonts?

Comment: Why don't you just use text-shadow property instead?

Comment: you should use negative margin-top to have the needed effect

Comment: Your desired result is not clear to me. Could you please add an image of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this..

```
.a {
  font-family: "Itim", cursive;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
}
.b {
  font-family: "Sedgwick Ave", cursive;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Only one of them should have `position:absolute` and the parent should have `position:relative`. If not, they're going to overlap with whatever is in document flow.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use `text-shadow`:

```css
h1 {
  font-family: Lobster; 
  font-size: 4.2rem;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,.27),.1em .2em 7px #bbb; 
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
}
h1 span {
  color: #c33;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet">

<h1>Use text shadow, <span>don't clone</span> your HTML!</h1>
```